# Cron file syntax checker/validator script

Tags: scripting, cron

Does anyone know a script (`bash`, `perl`, `php` ...) to validate the syntax of crontab files?

I found this http://www.intuitive.com/wicked/showscript.cgi?053-verifycron.sh but just Vixie `cron` notation is not supported (eg, 2-6/2).

Comment: You definitely want to check a question of mine. It has an answer by Stephane Chazelas that explains how you can create an interactive shell that is identical to the environment your cron job will see. If you walk through his little procedure, you get a prompt and you can test your script step by step and see where it fails. unix.stackexchange.com/a/56503/16841 Sure it isn't a 100% match for your question, but it can help you troubleshoot crontab issues.

Comment: This depends on the cron implementation used.

Comment: Validate to what level of detail? The last element of a crontab line is a shell command. A maximally correct validator for crontab files must parse shell syntax.